# Foreign Key not displaying in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm a bit new to the MVC approach. I have started with the database model first.  I currently have two tables:

- Fixtures
- Teams

Fixtures (amongst other fields) has a FK link to the team table for home and away team.

```
 public class Team
 {        
    public virtual int TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int DivisionId { get; set; }
 }

 public class Fixture
 {
    public int FixtureId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
 }
```

I notice when this comes through to the FixtureController both the HomeTeam and AwayTeam objects are null.  Do I have to somehow wire this inside the controller or should it automatically make the connection?

So ideally then in the view I can have:

```
<td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HomeTeam.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AwayTeam.Name)
    </td>
```

So I suppose my question is how do I get my controller to make the link from Fixtures->Team?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, use `.Include` to get the data. See also: [Loading Related Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx)

```
var fixtures = db.Fixtures // The fixture data
    .Include(fixture => fixture.HomeTeam)  // Bring in the HomeTeam
    .Include(fixture => fixture.AwayTeam); // Bring in the AwayTeam
```

Comment: Note that the above uses an extension in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace, so you'd want an `using System.Data.Entity;`. Alternatively, you can use the standard `Include` that takes a string path of what to load, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the quick reply, and more importantly the link.